# Python for loop prediction tuple error - LSTM model

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have built a 1 layer LSTM model that predicts future ride-hailing demand 1 hour into the future.

To test robustness, I want to repeat predictions multiple times and average the RSME score. Following this [example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-network-python/?unapproved=539929&moderation-hash=dbb7f5e4bb7ddc746951f8776b7ef7b1#comment-539929), I want to use a for loop to achieve this.

This piece of code includes a function that fits the LSTM model and a function that makes predictions:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from statsmodels.tools.eval_measures import rmse
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from math import sqrt

def fit_lstm(x_train_scaled, y_train_scaled, batch, ep, neurons_lstm, neuron_dense):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=neurons_lstm, input_shape=(x_train_scaled.shape[1], x_train_scaled.shape[2])))
    model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
    model.add(Dense(units=neuron_dense))
    model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", 
                  optimizer="adam",
                 )

    history = model.fit(x_train_scaled, 
                    y_train_scaled, 
                    epochs=ep, 
                    batch_size=batch, 
                    validation_split=0.1, 
                    verbose=2, 
                    shuffle=False)
    return model, history

def predictions_lstm(x_test_scaled, y_test):
    # get predictions
    test_pred = model.predict(x_test_scaled)

    # reverse transform predictions
    test_pred_inv = y_scaler.inverse_transform(test_pred)

    # reverse differencing predictions
    inverted_pred = list()
    for i in range(len(test_pred_inv)):
        value = inverse_difference(df_lstm.iloc[:,0], test_pred_inv[i], len(test_pred_inv)-i)
        inverted_pred.append(value)
    inverted_pred = pd.DataFrame(inverted_pred)

    # reverse differencing y_test
    inverted_ytest = list()
    for i in range(len(y_test)):
        value = inverse_difference(df_lstm.iloc[:,0], y_test[i], len(y_test)+1-i)
        inverted_ytest.append(value)
    inverted_ytest = pd.DataFrame(inverted_ytest)

    # create single dataframe with predictions (1) and expected values (2)
    predictions = np.concatenate((inverted_pred, inverted_ytest), axis=1)
    predictions = pd.DataFrame(predictions)

    return test_pred, test_pred_inv, predictions
```

This is the function that causes the tuple error. As you can see, I created a for loop with the prediction function from above.

```
repeats = 30
error_scores = list()

def repeat_pred_lstm(repeats):
    for i in range(repeats):
        # fit the model
        model= fit_lstm(x_train_scaled, 
                    y_train_scaled, 
                    batch=100, ep=10, 
                    neurons_lstm=5, 
                    neuron_dense=1)
        # make predictions
        predictions = predictions_lstm(x_test_scaled, y_test)
        # report performance
        rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(predictions[0], predictions[1]))
        mse_error = rmse**2
        error_scores.append(rmse)

    # summarize the results
    results = pd.DataFrame()
    results["rmse"] = error_scores
    print(results.head())
    print(results.describe())
    results.boxplot()

    return results

results = repeat_pred_lstm(repeats)
```

However, the for loop gives me the following error, which I don't understand because to my understanding there is no tuple object in the prediction function. To my understanding the input to make predictions for a LSTM model always has to be a numpy array and not a tuple.:

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-8c61191ae4b3> in <module>
     27     return results
     28 
---> 29 results = repeat_pred_lstm(repeats)

<ipython-input-44-8c61191ae4b3> in repeat_pred_lstm(repeats)
     11                         neuron_dense=1)
     12         # make predictions
---> 13         predictions = predictions_lstm(x_test_scaled, y_test)
     14         # report performance
     15         rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(predictions[0], predictions[1]))

<ipython-input-39-5b4f5fdbedd3> in predictions_lstm(x_test_scaled, y_test)
      1 def predictions_lstm(x_test_scaled, y_test):
      2     # get predictions
----> 3     test_pred = model.predict(x_test_scaled)
      4 
      5     # reverse transform predictions

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

I am able to get a RMSE score when I simply make predictions once with the "predictions_lstm(x_test_scaled, y_test) function", but when I use the for loop, the "predictions_lsmt(x_test_scaled, y_test) function" gives an error.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

`fit_ltsm` returns a tuple: `return model, history`.
However, you don't handle the history piece, meaning here, you have model set to the entire tuple, not the actual model:

```
 model= fit_lstm(x_train_scaled, 
                    y_train_scaled, 
                    batch=100, ep=10, 
                    neurons_lstm=5, 
                    neuron_dense=1)
```

You can fix this by splitting the return into two variables like:

```
  model, history = fit_ltsm(. . .)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is with the `fit_lstm` function. It returns a tuple and you have caught the tuple as a single variable `model`, change

```
        model= fit_lstm(x_train_scaled, 
                    y_train_scaled, 
                    batch=100, ep=10, 
                    neurons_lstm=5, 
                    neuron_dense=1)
```

to

```
        model,history= fit_lstm(x_train_scaled, 
                    y_train_scaled, 
                    batch=100, ep=10, 
                    neurons_lstm=5, 
                    neuron_dense=1)
```

Comment: Please post it as a question with necessary details

Comment: Rohin, never mind. I got it to work. Thanks again for you quick response.